# Nokogiri xml parsing on OSX Lion vs Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, nokogiri, ubuntu-10.04

I am running this ruby script:

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"USASCII\" ?>"

parsed = Nokogiri.parse(xml)
p parsed
```

When I run it on OSX Lion (ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]) it prints what I expect:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x85fd9ed8 name="document">
```

When I run the same script on Ubuntu 10.04.3 ruby-1.9.2-p290 I get an *Unsupported encoding USASCII (Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError)*

```
/home/stewie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peon/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:33:in `read_memory': Unsupported encoding USASCII (Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError)
    from /home/stewie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peon/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:33:in `parse'
    from /home/stewie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peon/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/xml.rb:33:in `XML'
    from /home/stewie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peon/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri.rb:82:in `parse'
    from nick.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I checked my locale on Ubuntu and things look okay:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Update:** On Ubuntu if I change USASCII to US-ASCII the error goes away.

So why does the script work on Lion but not Ubuntu?  Is there some difference with the libxml2 parsing ability?

Comment: What versions of Nokogiri / libxml are you using - what does `nokogiri -v` show?

Answer (score 1):

So use `US-ASCII`.

```
strings /usr/lib/libxml2.so | grep USASCII
strings /usr/lib/libxml2.so | grep US-ASCII
US-ASCII
```

... and the same result with `/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dynlib`. Strange. I suppose Mac does define `USASCII` as encoding, whereas Linux doesn't.